# Single model doesn't show with router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I can not understand how to show a single product. When I want to show product page (model view - app.ProductItemView in productPageShow) I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at child.productPageShow (some.js:58)" >> this.prod = this.prodList.get(id);

Here is my code:

```
// Models
var app = app || {};
app.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        coverImage: 'img/placeholder.png',
        id: '1',
        name: 'Unknown',
        price: '100'
    }
});

app.ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Product,
    url: 'php/listProducts.php'
});

// Views
app.ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#product-list',
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new app.ProductList();
        this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderProduct(item);
        }, this);
    },

    renderProduct: function(item) {
        app.productView = new app.ProductView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(app.productView.render().el);
    }
});

app.ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#productPage').html()),

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

app.ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#productTemplate').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});

// Router
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "list": 'list',
        "product/:id": "productPageShow"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.$content = $("#product-list");
    },

    list: function() {
        this.prodList = new app.ProductList();
        this.productListView = new app.ProductListView({ model: this.prodList });
        this.prodList.fetch();
        this.$content.html(app.productListView.el);
    },

    productPageShow: function(id) {
        this.prod = this.prodList.get(id);
        this.prodItView = new app.ProductItemView({ model: this.prod });
        this.$content.html(this.prodItView.el);
    }
});

$(function() {
    new app.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: Indent 4 spaces for code blocks, keep the description content focused on the question, write in proper english, include a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Emile thank you for your comment. But I really think that there is a minimal information to understand my question

Comment: What's the error? What's happening? Does the product list appears correctly?

Comment: Yes Emile. The product list appears correctly. But when I want to show product page (model view - app.ProductItemView in productPageShow) I get  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at child.productPageShow (some.js:58)" >> this.prod = this.prodList.get(id);

Comment: Please update the question with relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some conceptual problems with the code, without getting into too much details, there are a lot of things happening in the Router that don't belong there, but for a (currently) non-complex application that's manageable.

I'll focus on the app.Router file because that's the culprit of your problems most probably.

```
routes: {
    "list": 'list',
    "product/:id": "productPageShow"
}
```

Let's start with the basics, when you define a list of routes in Backbone Router( or any other Router in other frameworks ) you give a route a key that will correspond to something in the URL that the Router will recognize and call a callback method.

If you navigate your browser to:

```
http://your-url#list
```

Backbone will call the `list` callback

Similarly:

```
http://your-url#product/1
```

Backbone will call `productPageShow` callback

Thing to know: **ONLY ONE ROUTE CALLBACK CAN EVER BE CALLED!** The first time a Backbone Router finds a matching route it will call that callback and skip all others.

In your code you're relying on the fact that this.prodList will exist in `productPageShow` method but that will only happen if you first go to `list` route and then to `product/{id}` route.

Another thing .. in your `list`callback in the Router you set a `model` on the ProductListView instance .. but that `model` is neither user, nor is it a `model` since `this.productList` is a `Backbone.Collection`

Additionally, you need to know that `fetch` is an asynchronous action, and you're not using any callbacks to guarantee that you'll have the data when you need it ( other than relying on the 'reset' event ).

So this would be my attempt into making this workable:

```
// Models
var app = app || {};
app.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        coverImage: 'img/placeholder.png',
        id: '1',
        name: 'Unknown',
        price: '100'
    }
});

app.ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Product,
    url: 'php/listProducts.php'
});

// Views
app.ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#product-list',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderProduct(item);
        }, this);
    },

    renderProduct: function(item) {
        app.productView = new app.ProductView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(app.productView.render().el);
    }
});

app.ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#productPage').html()),

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

app.ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#productTemplate').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});

// Router
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
        "product/:id": "productPageShow"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.$content = $("#product-list");
    },

    list: function() {
        this.prodList = new app.ProductList();
        this.productListView = new app.ProductListView({ collection: this.prodList });
        this.prodList.fetch({reset:true});
        this.$content.html(app.productListView.el);
    },

    productPageShow: function(id) {
        try {
            this.prod = this.prodList.get(id);
            this.prodItView = new app.ProductItemView({ model: this.prod });
            this.$content.html(this.prodItView.el);
        } catch (e) {
            // Navigate back to '' route that will show the list
            app.Router.navigate("", {trigger:'true'})
        }

    }
});

$(function() {
    app.Router = new app.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

So with a bit of shooting in the dark without the complete picture, this is what changed:

- `ProductListView` is no longer instantiating `ProductList` collection that is done in the `list` callback in `Router`
- Changed the route from 'list' to '', that will guarantee that the list is shown immediately
- In case there are no product data available in `productPageShow` navigate back to `list`

Comment: There are a lot more improvements that could be made, and you were in the right direction, **but a try-catch isn't an improvement**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mario. I will try to use this information in the backbone study.

Comment: @EmileBergeron .. I know that there are other things to improve, and my version would probably be completely different than this one, but I just wanted to help with immediate problem without changing much of the original code. I usually practice progressive improvement, and if the try-catch solves the problem it's a new starting point for a new improvement, and I don't see anything wrong in that :)

Comment: @Vovix .. glad to hear, hope it will help in the long run. If you found this answer helpful and it solved your problem feel free to accept is as an answer :)